# Kubuntu will start with a black screen

Tags: kubuntu

When I tried installing Kubuntu desktop environment, I get a black screen when starting it.

I can see it load, but once it is done loading, it is just a black screen.

Is there a way that I can fix this, and get the actual environment to start?

Thanks!

Comment: I figured out that plasmashell solved the problem! When I went to terminal and typed plasmashell, kubuntu loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install Kubuntu on top of an existing Ubuntu installation of another flavor? If so you might have a conflict with window managers trying to start simultaneously. If you can open a terminal, run "plasmashell" and see if your KDE environment loads. If this works, you need to figure out how to stop the previously installed WM from starting when starting a plasma session.

Comment: Thanks, and it worked, but the command plasmashell was more effective.

Comment: haha, yeah sorry for typo